# OpenGL framebuffer depth not working

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, opengl-3

When I just use the back buffer this works fine but when I use a framebuffer the objects aren't rendered at a distance greater than 1 (in view space). This is using an OpenGL 3.2 context.

```
    colorTextureID = GL11.glGenTextures();
    depthTexutreID = GL11.glGenTextures();
    frameBufferID = GL30.glGenFramebuffers();

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTextureID);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
    GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (ByteBuffer) null);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexutreID);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL14.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, width, height, 0, GL11.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL11.GL_FLOAT, (ByteBuffer) null);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferID);
    GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTextureID, 0);
    GL32.glFramebufferTexture(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, depthTexutreID, 0);

    if (GL30.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        throw new RuntimeException("Frame buffer is not complete");

    GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: Check you view and projection matrices

Comment: It works fine when I don't use a framebuffer so it's nothing to do with the matrices.

Comment: Technically, there is no way you render without using a framebuffer.. Try `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F`, there may be a driver conversion going on

Comment: It still doesn't work with `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F`

Comment: I am using OpenGL 3.2 if that makes any difference.

Comment: @elect Should I be using a render buffer for the depth instead of a texture?

Comment: Someone says renderbuffers offer slightly more performances, but from mine profiling they are equivalent. However they are actually more limited than textures, so I'd say no, just stick with textures

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was nothing to do with the framebuffer I forgot to set the model and view matrices to the identity when I rendered the framebuffer.